# Simple add foreign key returns #1215 cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am sure I am missing something simple.

RequestLog table:

```
CREATE TABLE `requestlog` (
 `RequestID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `RequestName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `RequestData` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `RequestDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `Version` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`RequestID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

ResponseLog table:

```
CREATE TABLE `responselog` (
 `ResponseID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `FK_RequestID` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `ResponseText` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ResponseID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Trying to add a foreign key on ResponseLog.FK_RequestID with

```
ALTER TABLE ResponseLog
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FK_RequestID) REFERENCES RequestLog(RequestID)
```

Don't shoot me, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE` references tables `ResponseLog` and `RequestLog`. Your `CREATE TABLE` statements create tables named `requestlog` and `responselog`. Try changing your `ALTER TABLE` statement so that it uses table identifiers with the same case.

Also, and it is probably the main problem, the referenced fields have different data types. One is an int, the other an unsigned int. Data types have to match, otherwise the fields could become inconsistent. MySQL knows this and prevents you from creating a broken foreign key.

Comment: The main problem is the datatype mismatch: the datatype of the referring column does *not* match the referenced column. **`INT`** does not match **`INT UNSIGNED`**.

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured too. Table name mismatch was just too prominent.